# How to head off problem players before they start?

Tags: system-agnostic, new-players, problem-players, new-gm

I am about to embark on my first campaign as a GM (D&D 5e if you think that might be relevant), and I will be leading this game for a whole slew of new players. Most of the players seem great, I might need to corall them every once in a while, but nothing extreme. There is one player, however, that concerns me.

This player will most likely be drunk and high every time we play. That's not necessarily an issue, I ran an introductory one-off for the group and everyone else was similarly altered, but kept it together. The player in question was farther gone than everyone else, to the point where he could not focus much on what was going on.

In addition to that, he works a graveyard shift and will have to leave early almost every session. He wants to explain that in game by playing an older, senile, narcoleptic wizard. Again, I have no problem with the character choice, as long as the player is still involved.

To further complicate the matter, the potential problem player is the roommate of another player, who happens to be the one that gathered the group together. I don't want any actions that I take to strain their relationship over a game, but I still want everyone to play and have fun.

Now, I might be overly pessimistic here and he could turn out great, which I sincerely hope he does. However, I was wondering if anyone on this site had any experience dealing with players that you could sense might be a problem before the game even started. How did you communicate with them to lay down expectations and requirements for proper table etiquette?

Comment: Have you asked this player how much he actually wants to be there? If he is there only because his roommate assembled the group, he may be seeking an out just as much as you want him gone.

Comment: His roommate had the suspicion that he initially only wanted to be there because of a particular girl that wanted to play, but now that he's tried it once he liked it more than he thought he would.  And I want to make it clear that I don't necessarily want him gone, I just want to make sure that he doesn't turn into dead weight at the table slowing down the rest of the party.

Comment: _"In addition to that, he works a graveyard shift and will have to leave early almost every session."_ To what extent is he leaving early? Is this a two hour game where he leaves in the last twenty minutes? A three hour game where he leaves 1½ hours in? Something else?

Comment: If I knew I would give you more specifics, unfortunately we haven't had our first session yet, only the one-off where we were a little late to start anyway.

Comment: What, to you, does a "problem" consist of, given that the whole party appears to be baked?

Comment: As I said in the post, I don't have a problem with the players not being sober, but the others were still fully cognizant and aware of the situation. They might have been a bit more giggly and distractable, but they were still playing. This player had to be reminded of the scenario every five minutes, and his most effective move in combat was casting Light on an enemy.

Answer (score 6):

**Talk with your group.**

Very often, I find that intragroup conflicts come from expectation mismatches.

If your player expects to play a free-association storytelling game, or to just hang out and occasionally improv or "hit it with my axe!", his narcoleptic wizard and altered consciousness are appropriate and good. If you expect Tolkein-style storytelling or detailed tactical skirmishes, then sober, dedicated planning is appropriate instead. Both games would fall under the "RPG" heading, but one could very easily enjoy only one style.

So, think of it like a board game: some people like chess, some people like Apples to Apples, some people like Twilight Imperium, *and there's nothing wrong with that!* If you were discussing what board game to play, you'd want to talk about what each unfamiliar game is like, not just present names. A game like D&D accommodates a wide variety of play-styles, so it's really important to talk ahead of time, and to check back often that everyone is still having fun.

The [Same Page Tool](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/) is consistently recommended as an aid for this discussion, and I'll point you there as well.

Finally, as a useful bonus: it's far easier to do GM preparation when you know what your players want.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to present somehwat of a frame challenge here:  you might want to eliminate that initial seed of doubt about the player from your own mind.  It sounds like you're already off to a worse start than you could have by simply removing your expectations of the player entirely and letting the situation unfold naturally.

**Simply put:  he isn't a problem player yet, *so don't sweat it*.**  Your expectation that he will *become* a problem player isn't meaningful in reality, and will only lead to confirmation bias down the road when you start 'seeing' things that you perceive as problems due to that player, which in turn will create more problems at the table than you would have if you let your concerns go.  In other words, what you think will happen is almost certainly not the same as what will happen.  The good news is, you're self-aware enough to say this:

> Now, I might be overly pessimistic here and he could turn out great, which I sincerely hope he does.

This is good because it means you're aware you could be wrong!  And in all likelihood you are worrying about a problem that may never occur.  And if it does occur, well, there are plenty of questions here and other resources online about dealing with *actual* problem players, so you're covered there, too.

My advice as a DM who was once in a similar position: let things happen naturally.  If he senses you're trying to steer him in a direction or that you're treating him differently because of your assumptions about him, it's going to create tension that wouldn't have otherwise existed.  Remember what they say about making assumptions.

Best to just drop all expectations and remove the bias from yourself as much as  you can.  Players play for all sorts of different reasons; his reasons for playing may differ from others but that doesn't make him wrong.

Comment: I received a downvote but I'm not sure why.  How can I improve my answer?  What about it is not useful?

Answer (score 3):

For players who might not show up, or might "not be all there" during play, or who otherwise might fail to play or fail to roleplay or drop out or get kicked out, the GM can/should think in advance about what to do in those cases. Some options I have used which worked well for me include:

- Have the PC's character be somewhat aligned with the player's. If the player's going to be high, then it can help if his PC is also someone flaky in a way that corresponds. Maybe they are mystical, or a stoner themselves, or have brain damage, or are space aliens, or just are generally far out or have unpredictable (or multiple/split, or schizophrenic) personality. That way, the stoned player is sort of just roleplaying. Don't have the stoner's PC be someone who's supposed to be a highly rational and consistent person where the adventure depends on them being there all the time.
- Figure out how you will roleplay the player's character if/when they don't make it to the game, or stop playing or get weird during a game. This is good to think about for all the PC's, since sometimes anyone might not show up. It's also good to get agreement from the players about this, and ask them how they want you to play their characters if/when they are not there.
- Think about where you want the line to be where you start re-interpreting they player's input or overruling it, if it gets too far out. This is also good to talk about and get agreement with the player at some time between sessions when they are not high.
- Have actual in-game reasons why some PC's might not be available for some or all of some sessions. In a game that concludes at some safe space between sessions, you can have the PCs of absent players be unavailable to adventure at that time due to in-game reasons, such as being required by their employers or patrons or family or something. Depending on the setting you may be able to arrange for the group to be split in cases where some players can't make it, and just have the PCs of absent players need to go somewhere else to do something for a bit. I have also had cases where there was an in-game explanation why some PCs might vanish if/when the player wasn't available - either through magic or intra-dimensional technobabble or mysterious cosmic reasons, the character would actually phase out - and this could apply to when a player got called away... or got drunk.